# C# web scraping Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, web-scraping

Suppose my website has source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hello">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function simple() 
        {
            $("#hello").append("<p>Hello</p>");
        }                    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a C#/asp.Net method to extract it's source code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hello">
    </div>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

> string src=new WebClient().DownloadString("http://mywebsite.com")

doesn't help as it extracts the raw html code along with the javascript, same as the source code.

Comment: @mshsayem No it won't.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to download only HTML source page and not any script code?

Comment: @mshsayem It seems that OP doesn't want scriptless html, He/She wants scripts to be executed. see the `<p>Hello</p>` in html.

Comment: @l4v ooo, I see now. Misunderstood the problem. Thanks

Comment: @mshsayem yes exactly
i want the html code after script has been executed
can you help?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the comments above I understand that you're looking for the scripts to be executed before you get the final HTML DOM.

What you need is a JavaScript engine to run the scripts, the basic mechanics of a browser. 
Depending on your needs, you can either implement this yourself with V8 (Chrome's JavaScript engine) or SpiderMonkey (Mozilla's JavaScript engine) or use one of the two popular headless browser frameworks: PhantomJS and CasperJS. Using them will also cover all your future AJAX needs should you have any.